# Vuejs 2 reload content by changing slug

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I have the following code and it works by refreshing the page it works fine, but not when clicking on the nav.

How can i achieve that when i click on users, the method fetchData will be executed? So i can see the console.log and the json data.

Navigation:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <router-link  v-for="item in items" v-if="item.navitems && item.navitems.navitem" :to="item.navitems.navitem.url" tag="li" active-class="active" exact><a>{{item.navitems.navitem.name}}</a></router-link>
```

Content.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>{{ slug }}</h1>
            <ul v-if="items && items.length">
                <li v-for="item of items">
                    <p><strong>{{item.name}}</strong></p>
                    <p>{{item.email}}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        props: ['slug'],
        data: () => ({
            items: []
        }),
        created: function () {
            this.fetchData();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchData: function () {
                var self = this;
                console.log(this.slug);
                $.get( 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/' + this.slug, function( data ) {
                    self.items = data;
                    console.log(data);
                });

            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed created into mounted and add watch.

```
    watch: {
        '$route.params.slug'(newSlug, oldSlug) {
            this.fetchData(newId);
        }
    }
```